# error: with-readline=yes (default) and headers/lib are not available

Tags: r, installation, package

I am trying to install RHadoop. I have used following instruction in a Virtual box Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit version.
    $wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/r-base/2.15.1-3ubuntu1/+files/r-base_2.15.1.orig.tar.gz

```
$ tar -zxvf r-base_2.15.1.orig.tar.gz
$ sudo apt-get install gfortran
$ cd R-2.15.1/
$ ./configure --with-x=no
```

When I run this command, I get the error mentioned above. Google also does not have any suggestions for this error although many talk about X11

Comment: Is that an exact copy of the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Readline is a GNU package that you can find [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/readline/); your first option consists in installing it before trying to build R again.

Alternatively, if you are sure you do not need R to be built with this library, you can simply set with-readline to "no":

```
./configure --with-x=no --with-readline=no
```

Comment: passing =no would turn R unusable with a GUI/graphics, just a comment in case someone opt for this 'solution'

Answer (score 2):

Setting readline to no is something I considered, but than think of this, what if you need it. I am not even sure what it is 100%, but I assume it lets R read from user input of some sort.

Anyways, I just resolved this error by installing readline-devel on centos via yum. On debian I think it's something like libreadline-dev. The point is that you need development files which include .h files necessary for R.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me:

error: --with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available
Solution:
Code:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

For Centos 7, to install X11

```
# yum install xorg-x11-server-devel libX11-devel libXt-devel
```

Now ./configure